# How to get the active version of a SAPUI5 application deployed in Hana Cloud Platform

Tags: javascript, jquery, sapui5, sap-cloud-platform

I have a requirement where I need to alert the end user when a new version of the SAPUI5 application is deployed and activated.

How to get the **active/current** version of a SAPUI5 application deployed in Hana Cloud Platform using jQuery/Javascript.