# Can I access the active version on SAP Cloud Platform of HTML5 apps through a api?

Tags: sapui5, sap-cloud-platform

I need to access the active version on SAP Cloud Platform of HTML5 apps through an api.

I know for the java apps you have the lifecycle api: [doc](https://api.hana.ondemand.com/lifecycle/v1/documentation)

But you can't access HTML5 information with this API.

What I found is this service: `https://account.hana.ondemand.com/ajax/getHtml5AppDetails/{subaccountName}/{appName}`

This will return a JSON string with the required info, but I'm not authorized to access this page, although I have all the possible admin rights.

So I'm wondering If any of you has any idea to solve my issue, and [other people's issues.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46784254/how-to-get-the-active-version-of-a-sapui5-application-deployed-in-hana-cloud-pla)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, we needed something similar and used this kinda hack to get the active versions via WebIde Api (need basic Auth to login) replace XXXX with your account

```
https://webide-XXXX.dispatcher.hana.ondemand.com/api/html5api/accounts/XXXXX/applications
```

You get back a json array with all your applications of that sub account, including active version and other interesting information

Hope it helps ;))

Regards Mathias

Answer (score 1):

You could create a HTTP Proxy Servlet based on https://github.com/SAP/cloud-connectivityproxy that provides read only access to `https://dispatcher.hanatrial.ondemand.com/hcproxy/b/api/accounts/<subaccount>/applications/<app>` for your app.

Comment: Thanks for this, I was thinking to do the same but was hoping on some other/more standard solution provided by SAP. Will already start with the proxy but if anyone has a alternative solution please share.