# sap cloud platform List HTML5 Applications via API or CLI Tool

Tags: sap-business-technology-platform

is there an API or CLI Tool to display all HTML5 Applications and there current active version of an subaccount.

We need this for our build / deploy chain and work in the NEO Environment.

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48258495/can-i-access-the-active-version-on-sap-cloud-platform-of-html5-apps-through-a-ap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48258495/can-i-access-the-active-version-on-sap-cloud-platform-of-html5-apps-through-a-ap)